# Laravel using functions in mail templates with queue

Tags: email, laravel, queue, laravel-4, amazon-sqs

In my email templates I use the `asset()` function to get url of images. I send emails using `Mail::queue` method with Amazon SQS service. When I got the email I don't see any pictures, instead I get only  tag without src.

The same problem I encountered when I passed to email some eloquent objects, like user, and I was trying to get $user->name in email template. There was an error `Object not found` and it only happened when I used Mail::queue. Now, instead of passing eloquent object in mail I just pass some data that I retrieved before, like

```
$data = [ 'name' => $user->name ];
```

Is it okay that asset() and eloquent and probably other functions don't work when queuing or I'm missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use a closure?

Comment: http://paste.laravel.com/1gFx here is the code